# Space Issue being caused due to Weblogic Server warning messages

Tags: windows, logging, server, weblogic

We have CRM running on seven clustered servers which comprises of our Front End. We have another cluster the Process Manager Cluster comprising of two other machines. These two machines are running weblogic 8.1 windows installation and random nodes on these servers are causing zero space issue due to the logs getting full as a result of a warning message.

There is no change done to the code since ages. What can be the issue here?

```
####<12-Mar-2007 15:29:35 o'clock GMT> <Alert> <Log Management> <Server1> <scm1-04> <ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<anonymous>> <> <BEA-170018> <The log file has been rotated to scm1-04.log17956. Log messages will continue to be logged in D:\logs\scm1-04.log.> 
####<12-Mar-2007 15:29:35 o'clock GMT> <Warning> <EJB> <Server1> <scm1-04> <ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<anonymous>> <> <BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at com.clarify.procmgr.ejb.ProcessManagerMDB.onMessage(ProcessManagerMDB.java:58)
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:370)
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:262)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:2678)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:2598)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:219)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>
```

Comment: These logs are old but the warning message is relevant.....

Comment: Post the complete stack trace to see the root cause of the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Will this help?

Comment: <BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
 at com.clarify.procmgr.ejb.ProcessManagerMDB.onMessage(ProcessManagerMDB.java:58)
 at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:370)
 at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:262)
 at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:2678)

Comment: not realy, post the complete stack trace. You will get it from the weblogic server's log file.